# Best way to manage assembly reference in a .Net project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assemblies

I have a solution which contains 108 projects. There are few projects which are referred in other projects.

I am simplifying the solution and taking projects out of the solution and managing the assembly references via a folder now.

I will try to illustrate the problem in simple manner now.

Let's say in my solution, I have project FATHER, SON and CLIENT. Client has reference to SON and SON has reference to FATHER.
When I build CLIENT, the bin folder contains client.exe, son.dll and father.dll

Now I have created a new solution for the CLIENT and placed SON.DLL in a SharedAssly folder. But when I run the CLIENT.EXE, I get error Could not load assembly FATHER.DLL.

Now I understand that if I add a reference of FATHER.DLL in client too and I place FATHER.DLL also in SharedAssly folder, it will work.

But looking at the complexity of my solution and umpteen number of nested dependencies, this seems to be a herculin task as FATHER AND SON both have their lot of dependencies on internal projects and several NUGET packages.

Is there an easy way to manage this? I am using .Net 4.8 and VS2019

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nuget solves this.  Download the Nuget CLI if necessary, Package and publish father and son assemblies to a local nuget repository (folder).

Comment: @Cobster - thanks mate, Nuget is an upcoming work and I understand nuget can manage dependencies. At this point of time, I am seeking a way out to physical file references in the best possible way.